# Reducing MySQL query with multiple "OR" statements

Tags: mysql, sql

I am doing a query where i would like to find the smartest way to define OR statements to reduce my query dump.

I have following headers in my table:

```
| id | subscriber | phonenumber | type |
```

So i wish to make a query where i only want to fetch `type` values equal to `typeOne`, `typeTwo`and `typeThree`.

Which is the smartest way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [an `IN` clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in):

```
WHERE `type` IN ('typeOne', 'typeTwo', 'typeThree')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM YourTable
WHERE type IN ('typeOne', 'typeTwo','typeThree')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `WHERE fieldname IN (value1,value2,value3)`